# v-checkbox object model with vuetify

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

Are v-checkbox vuetify components not working as expected? I'm trying to set an object as value but it seems to not works as I want, did I set something wrong?

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <p>{{ selected }}</p>
      <v-checkbox v-model="selected" label="A" value="A"></v-checkbox>
      <v-checkbox v-model="selected" label="my Object with v-checkbox" :value="{ 'id': 1, 'subId': 12 }"></v-checkbox>

<label>
    <input type="checkbox" :value="{ 'id': 1, 'subId': 12 }" v-model="selected">
    my Object with input type checkbox
</label>

    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      selected: ['A', { "id": 1, "subId": 12 }]
    }
  }
})
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OZYzYw?&editors=101

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is tricky. It's because [Javascript object is passed by reference](https://codeburst.io/javascript-pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference-in-javascript-fcf10305aa9c).

Firstly, how to make it work: https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/KRLQaK?editors=1010

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <p>{{ selected }}</p>
      <v-checkbox v-model="selected" label="A" value="A"></v-checkbox>
      <v-checkbox v-model="selected" label="Object" :value="checkboxObjectValue"></v-checkbox>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      selected: ["A"]
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.checkboxObjectValue = { id: 11, subId: 12 };
    this.selected.push(this.checkboxObjectValue);
  }
});
```

*Now the explanation...*

Javascript object is passed by reference. When you pass an object to something, it's not passing the entire object value, it's passing the reference. I like to think of it as passing the *address* of an object in memory.

When you do `:value="{ 'id': 1, 'subId': 12 }"` in v-checkbox, what happen is that everytime this component rerender, a new object is generated and assigned to the value. **A new object reference is passed to the value!** Therefore, when you pushed it to `selected`, it's considered a new object, so it just keeps on adding a new object to the `selected` array.

**To avoid this, create an object containing the value first. Then use this same object everywhere to avoid generating a new object. The value object should be generated once only.**

Comment: Nice explanation, how do you think I could do it into a for loop? something like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GdaxGo?editors=1010 I have an object array with more levels inside and I have to draw it as filters

Comment: @PriNcee  based on your example, simply changing `this.newSelected = { id:1, subId:11 };` to `this.newSelected = this.objectIds[0];` and it'll work. https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/yjWKrj?editors=1010 . The rule is the same: try not to create new object, always reuse the same object.

Comment: Nice! thank you a lot, so I can solve it this way: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GdaxGo?editors=1010